# multiselect ,autocomplete combobox in wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox, autocomplete

I was able to acheive a multiselect combobox using checkboxes.but that doesnt help if the items in the combobox are more than 600,as the user need to go through all the items in combobox to select.So I wanted to add AutoComplete feature too.But was wondering if thats possible in wpf.Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on how you've enabled multiselection. WPF's regular Combo supports text search and autocompletion out of the box, so this should be possible...

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly how you're populating your Combo and making multiselection work, this should at least serve as an example of how to enable text search and autocompletion:

```
    <ComboBox IsEditable="True" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True">
        <ComboBoxItem TextSearch.Text="Thing">
            <ComboBoxItem.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Thing" />
                </Grid>
            </ComboBoxItem.Content>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem TextSearch.Text="Stuff">
            <ComboBoxItem.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Stuff" />
                </Grid>
            </ComboBoxItem.Content>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

By using `TextSearch.Text` (or `TextSearch.TextPath`) you can define the text you want the Combo to use for searching, filtering and autocompleting user input.

By setting `IsEditable="True"`, you allow the user to enter text and do text searchs. With `StaysOpenOnEdit="True"` the user will be able to see the item he's looking for, and click its CheckBox if needed. And finally `IsTextSearchEnabled="True"` enables text search, obviously.